# Hardware acceleration error when starting Ubuntu 14.04 in VM

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, hardware-acceleration

When I attempt to start Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM I get this error (I have not started it before):

```
VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on this machine
```

What can I do?

Comment: it means that your CPU does not support virtualization or it has been disabled in BIOS. What is your CPU type ?

Comment: What variety of virtual machine are you running?

Comment: What software are you using? VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1):

Enable "virtualization" in your boot settings. It is "off" by default in most laptops.

As pointed out by Aizuddin Zali , may be vendor have locked in "Virtualization". Therefore can you just inform what Machine (machine number , company) you are using?

Comment: this also can be really a CPU that doesnt have virtualization dont you think? Vendor also can lock the virtualization capability in  certain laptop/pc.

Comment: @Aizuddin Zali , I think most CPU support virtualization nowadays.

Comment: most but not all, and we cant answer based on assumption. And we need to check as well if the vendor locking the virtualization or not in BIOS.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/ and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html articles clearly says that.

Comment: yes, the article is correct, but its not only bound to BIOS settings.  CPU must have virtualization capability, BIOS must be sets to make the virtualization on, BIOS also a software, vendor can lock the virtualization in it.  Check [this](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?id=20061018194933477&board_id=3&model=A8F&page=1&SLanguage=en-us) when Asus do a Vendor locked-in for Virtualization support.

Comment: @Aizuddin Zali , you are right about vendor's locking of Virtualization but that chip is too old and I think 99.9% of machines now have BIOS with virtualization on/off capability.

Comment: still some vendor still implement that nowadays,  my Lenovo G40-45 does not have that privileges even though AMD A6 supporting AMD-V.